# Can you trigger workflows and send data without user voice?

Tags: actions-on-google, google-home, google-smart-home

Suppose I had a bluetooth low-energy (BLE) device that periodically needed to send sensor data to my server. And I wanted to use a Google Home Hub as a **proxy** to send this data. Is it possible to send periodic actions or do all actions have to be triggered by a users voice?

From the documentation I see you need a Android App or Google Home App but can I build custom message interfaces without one?

Comment: did you take a look at https://developers.google.com/assistant/smarthome/develop/seamless-setup#notifications ?

Answer (score 1):

This can be made to work using two important aspects for smart home integration :

Local Home SDK , which enhances your smart home integration with Google Assistant by adding a local fulfillment path to route smart home intents. More information about how this works can be found here, https://developers.google.com/assistant/smarthome/concepts/local

Seamless Setup using Bluetooth Low Energy . Since BLE devices do not have a companion cloud fulfillment implementation, asynchronous state changes must be reported locally through the Local Home SDK. We would need to implement the connection event handlers, AUTOCONNECT and DISCONNECT. Also, implementation for subscribing to notifications from BLE devices needs to be carried out using REGISTER_FOR_NOTIFICATION command to the device using the DeviceManager API. Other steps to be carried out are for reporting characteristic state changes through PARSE_NOTIFICATIOn intent handler. More information about working around with this can be found here, https://developers.google.com/assistant/smarthome/develop/seamless-setup#reporting_local_device_state